# Node.js problem with http / https protocol

Tags: java, node.js

I included the SSL certificate on my website and did all the redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. There was probably a problem. Typing "nodejs driver" everything starts nicely (the driver.js file launches a bot on my site, which draws randomly), but the problem is that it occurs, I go to the site via HTTP to the bot works, and the use of https before it, unfortunately, does not work.

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: Please provide more description to your problem.

Comment: When I run the driver.js file via the 'nodejs driver' command on the http protocol works and on https it doesn't work

Comment: The problem appears after installing the ssl certificate